# Column width setting - HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/JN8Pm/1/ . This table is generated by gridview in asp.net. Hence I cannot add a class to “td” inside “tr”. [This is the suggestion in many forums; but that won't work for me due to gridview]

How can I

1. set the background color of Emp ID column as Red?
2. set the width of Emp ID column as 300px?

**Reference**:

Refer the following two for table styling

```
1. table-layout:fixed;
2. word-wrap:break-word;
```

1. [Using "word-wrap: break-word" within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889508/using-word-wrap-break-word-within-a-table)
2. [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)
3. [Adjusting HTML Table Cell Width using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993901/adjusting-html-table-cell-width-using-jquery)
4. [Table cells get hidden when total width is more than 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599659/table-cells-get-hidden-when-total-width-is-more-than-100)

Comment: Your asp.net code that generates this would probably be useful for answering your question. Post it?

Comment: @SRN Please see the width. It is not coming to 300px

Comment: Since the code is generated from ASP.NET you will have to modify the ASP.NET code, unless you want to use JS/jQuery to select and class the elements. Can you show the ASP.NET code or are you looking at the jQuery option?

Comment: @DiscoBanana I am fine with jQuery option if it can set the width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JN8Pm/8/

```
var table = $('#detailContentPlaceholder_grdTransactions'),
    trs = table.find('tr'),
    headTr = table.find('.second'),
    empHeader = $($(headTr).children('th')[1]);

table.width(table.width() + 300);

empHeader.css('background-color', 'red');
empHeader.width(300);

for (var i = 2; i < trs.length; i += 1) {    
    var td = $($(trs[i]).children('td')[1]);
    td.css('background-color', 'red');
    td.width(10);
}​
```

It's changing the color and the size of the EmplID column.
I hope that this is solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks.. Even http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/JN8Pm/10/ is fine for my real requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using jquery

```
 $('tr').each(function(index) {
     if (index > 1){
        $($(this).children()[1]).css("background-color","Red");

     }
     $($(this).children()[1]).css("width","300px");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JN8Pm/6/

The width change doesn't really work in jsfiddle it seems , but it should be something along those lines

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/JN8Pm/8/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/JN8Pm/10/ for working demo in fiddle :-)